# What would be the best way to store times of Algorithms

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The program is to analyse different sorting algorithms on different cases.
I want to store the algorithm name and with it i need to store 10 running time vales for case (a), then store separately 10 running values for case (b) 
Below is the code testing different sorting algorithms runtimes. My code loses the result after start of each algorithm as I dont know how to store them properly

```
def call(m):
    for i in range(m):
        makelist()

def makelist():
    lst=[10]
    for l in lst:
        testall(l)

def testall(n):
    flist = [insertionsort,selectionsort]
    if n < 1:
        n = 1
    testlist = [i for i in range(n)]
    lsr=[testlist.sort(),   testlist.sort(reverse=True),random.shuffle(testlist)]
    for f in flist:
        result=[]
        for g in lsr:
            copylist = copy.deepcopy(testlist)
            testfunction(copylist,f, result)

def testfunction(testlist, function,r):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    function(testlist)
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    print('time =', (end_time - start_time), '; alg =', function.__name__, '(', len(testlist), ')')
    r.append(end_time - start_time)
```

Comment: This is not the complete code. Please give complete code.

Comment: the rest of the code is just 2 sorting Algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Based on your outline, I'd suggest a defaultdict of list where the function name is the key and the various timings are appended to the value:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def testfunction(testlist, function, results):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    function(testlist)
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    print('time =', (end_time - start_time), '; alg =', function.__name__, '(', len(testlist), ')')
    results[function.__name__].append(end_time - start_time)


results = defaultdict(list)

for f in flist:
    for g in lsr:
        copylist = copy.deepcopy(testlist)
        testfunction(copylist, f, results)
```

When you're finished, results will contain something like:

```
>>> results
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'haresort': [6.194799953483277, 1.947999534832776, 9.47999534832776, 4.799953483277619, 7.999534832776194, 6.194799953483277, 1.947999534832776, 9.47999534832776, 4.799953483277619, 7.999534832776194], 'snailsort': [8.327761947999534, 3.277619479995348, 2.776194799953483, 7.761947999534832, 7.619479995348327, 8.327761947999534, 3.277619479995348, 2.776194799953483, 7.761947999534832, 7.619479995348327]})
```

Just treat the defaultdict as an ordinary dictionary for the most part.  For example, as the last thing you do in testall(), you can print out the contents of the results:

```
for function, timings in results.items():
    print(function, ":\n")
    print(*timings, sep="\n")
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks very much where the best place to put the code to print the dictionary, dont want it to print out till after its done all the calls.. Also is this good code to print out the dictionary                                                         for keys,values in results.items():
        print(keys)
        print(values)

Comment: @AssassinsMayCry I've added example print code to my answer.  My guess is that it should be the last thing that testall() does.